# Layer doesn't show with recycleview

Tags: android, json, xml, recyclerview-layout

I'm doing a bitcoin tracker app, so i can learn the basics of json parsing, but my app layer stays blank as i run the app. This is my **RecycleViewAdapter:**

```
package Adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestOptions;
import com.example.angel.simplecrypto.R;

import java.util.List;

import Models.Currencies;

public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter <RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<Currencies> mData;
    RequestOptions option;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context mContext, List<Currencies> mData) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mData = mData;
        option = new RequestOptions().centerCrop().placeholder(R.drawable.loading_shape).error(R.drawable.loading_shape);


    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view;
        LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.currency_row_item, parent,false);

        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.currency_price.setText(mData.get(position).getEur());
        holder.currency_price2.setText(mData.get(position).getUsd());



    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{


        TextView currency_price2;
        TextView currency_price;


        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);


            currency_price2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.price2);
            currency_price= itemView.findViewById(R.id.price);



        }
    }
}
```

**and this is my MainActivity:**

```
package Activities;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.example.angel.simplecrypto.R;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import Adapters.RecyclerViewAdapter;
import Models.Currencies;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final String JSON_URL = "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=BTC&tsyms=EUR,USD";
    private JsonArrayRequest request;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private List<Currencies> lstCurrencies;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lstCurrencies = new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerviewid);
        jsonrequest();
    }

    private void jsonrequest() {
        request = new JsonArrayRequest(JSON_URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++){

                    try{
                        jsonObject=response.getJSONObject(i);
                        Currencies currencies = new Currencies();
                        currencies.setEur(jsonObject.getString("EUR"));
                        currencies.setUsd(jsonObject.getString("USD"));


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            setuprecyclerview(lstCurrencies);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });



    }

    private void setuprecyclerview(List<Currencies> lstCurrencies) {

        RecyclerViewAdapter myadapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this, lstCurrencies);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        recyclerView.setAdapter(myadapter);
    }

}
```

I just wanted to test the recycle viewer with 2 items only, but i have no clue why nothing shows up. In my *activity_main.xml* i made the recyclerviewer and i have a *seperate .xml* for the design of the items in that recycleviewer. Any ideas? And btw i got this error: 04-21 18:20:11.707 26586-26586/com.example.angel.simplecrypto E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Comment: You are not really adding the new currency into `lstCurrencies`. In your try block add `lstCurrencies.add(currencies)` after `currencies.setUsd(...`

Answer (score 1):

I think you have forget `lstCurrencies.add(currencies);`

Comment: Tried it, still doesn't work:/ I've set the adapter, but when i look in the logcat i get this: *RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout*

Answer (score 0):

you need to add this in your `jsonrequest()` method

`lstCurrencies.add(currencies);`

and define your  `RecyclerViewAdapter` adapter class globaly and add `myadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` after adding data in listview

try like this...

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final String JSON_URL = "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=BTC&tsyms=EUR,USD";
    private JsonArrayRequest request;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private List<Currencies> lstCurrencies;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerViewAdapter myadapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lstCurrencies = new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerviewid);

        myadapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this, lstCurrencies);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        recyclerView.setAdapter(myadapter); 

        jsonrequest();
    }

    private void jsonrequest() {
        request = new JsonArrayRequest(JSON_URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++){

                    try{
                        jsonObject=response.getJSONObject(i);
                        Currencies currencies = new Currencies();
                        currencies.setEur(jsonObject.getString("EUR"));
                        currencies.setUsd(jsonObject.getString("USD"));
                        lstCurrencies.add(currencies);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });

     RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
     queue.add(request);

    } 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your json parse is not right so that data not show in recyclerview.Your API return json object and you will parse array.Check your API response and check your json parsing coding.